# AngularJS. Decorating model

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, decorator

Backend returns json like this:

```
[ 
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "the name",
    countryIds: [ 1,2,3]
  }, ...
]
```

As you can see there is `countryIds` property. On client side I already have cached country names with corresponding IDs:

```
[ 
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "USA"
  },
  { 
    id:2, name: "France"
  }...
]
```

, so when retrieving this objects I just add new `countries` property where I assign country names:

```
obj.countries = getCountryNamesByIds(obj.countryIds);
```

so my initial object then looks like this:

```
   {
        id: 1,
        name: "the name",
        countryIds: [ 1,2,3],
        countries: ["USA", "France", "England"]
      }
```

The problem is that when sending object to the server after updating (using `PUT` method) I don't want to send to the server the `countries` property. How I can handle this situation in more elegant way? To my mind comes few options:

1.When sending object to the server just remove all unnecessary properties (bad way, because if new property will be added to JSON then I need to apply same changes in controller logic too);

2.Don't decorate object with new `countries` proeprty, and expose some application-level methods like

> $rootScope.getCountryNamesByIds = getCountryNamesByIds;

and then use it in templates:

```
<label> Countries </label>
<div> {{getCountryNamesByIds(obj.countryIds)}} </div>
```

3.Don't decorate object with new `countries` proeprty, and create directive called `countryNames`which will generate country names from country IDs (as in point 2):

```
<div country-names country-ids="obj.countryIds"> // There will be shown country names generated from their IDs</div>
```

How you think, what option is more elegant? Or what is other way to solve my challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem a number of times, and tried all of the solutions. In general, I will do the following:

1. When it is something I may need to edit and send back, do not decorate, but instead use a separate list and lookup, like your #2 and #3.
2. When it is something I will not need to edit - e.g. using your example, if I need to add a registration for that object, so it is actually a separate resource - then decorate

A third possibility is to save it as a function on the object

```
obj.getCountries = function() {return [["USA", "France", "England"] ]; };
```

and then use it in the template

```
<div> {{obj.getCountries())}} </div>
```

FYI, I created a patch method for ng-resource, so I can save only the changes via PATCH. Doesn't help here, but was part of the same overall problem. In that case, it isn't too hard to extend it to say, "only send back those items that have been changed, not anything added", which would solve it as well.